# Issues with OpenGL rotation matricies and shaders

Tags: opengl, java, mathematics, matrix

I am having an issue with my rotations in my opengl shaders. My program works fine before I add in my rotation matrices. [Here is an example, at YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y9fAbH5hoEM). After I add rotations to my shaders, there are issues. [Here is an example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N3H1FaSmLC4).

---

Here is my vertex shader:

```
    #version 130

in vec3 position;
in vec4 color;
in vec2 texcoord;
uniform mat4 view_array;
uniform mat4 end_array;
uniform mat4 projection_matrix;
uniform mat4 trans_matrix;
uniform mat4 x_rotation_matrix;
uniform mat4 y_rotation_matrix;
uniform mat4 z_rotation_matrix;

out vec4 pos;
out vec2 texture_coordinate;
//out vec4 color_value;
void main()
{
     mat4 vw_matrix = mat4(1.0);
     mat4 rotation_matrix = x_rotation_matrix * y_rotation_matrix;
     mat4 model_matrix =  trans_matrix * rotation_matrix;//
     pos = projection_matrix * vw_matrix * model_matrix *  vec4(position, 1.0);
     gl_Position = pos;
     texture_coordinate = texcoord;
     //color_value = color
}
```

Here are the values for my matrices:

```
// rotation matrices

x_rotation_matrix[0] = 1;
x_rotation_matrix[1] = 0;
x_rotation_matrix[2] = 0;
x_rotation_matrix[3] = 0;
x_rotation_matrix[4] = (float) cos(-yaw * (PI / 180));
x_rotation_matrix[5] = (float) -sin(-yaw * (PI / 180));
x_rotation_matrix[6] = 0;
x_rotation_matrix[7] = (float) sin(-yaw * (PI / 180));
x_rotation_matrix[8] = (float) cos(-yaw * (PI / 180));
x_rotation_matrix[9] = 0;
x_rotation_matrix[10] = 1;
x_rotation_matrix[11] = 0;
x_rotation_matrix[12] = 0;
x_rotation_matrix[13] = 0;
x_rotation_matrix[14] = 0;
x_rotation_matrix[15] = 1;

y_rotation_matrix[0] = (float) cos(-pitch * (PI / 180));
y_rotation_matrix[1] = 0;
y_rotation_matrix[2] = (float) sin(-pitch * (PI / 180));
y_rotation_matrix[3] = 0;
y_rotation_matrix[4] = 0;
y_rotation_matrix[5] = 1;
y_rotation_matrix[6] = (float) -sin(-pitch * (PI / 180));
y_rotation_matrix[7] = 0;
y_rotation_matrix[8] = (float) cos(-pitch * (PI / 180));
y_rotation_matrix[9] = 0;
y_rotation_matrix[10] = 1;
y_rotation_matrix[11] = 0;
y_rotation_matrix[12] = 0;
y_rotation_matrix[13] = 0;
y_rotation_matrix[14] = 0;
y_rotation_matrix[15] = 1;

z_rotation_matrix[0] = (float) cos(-pitch * (PI / 180));
z_rotation_matrix[1] = (float) -sin(-pitch * (PI / 180));
z_rotation_matrix[2] = 0;
z_rotation_matrix[3] = (float) sin(-pitch * (PI / 180));
z_rotation_matrix[4] = (float) cos(-pitch * (PI / 180));
z_rotation_matrix[5] = 1;
z_rotation_matrix[6] = 0;
z_rotation_matrix[7] = 0;
z_rotation_matrix[8] = 0;
z_rotation_matrix[9] = 0;
z_rotation_matrix[10] = 1;
z_rotation_matrix[11] = 0;
z_rotation_matrix[12] = 0;
z_rotation_matrix[13] = 0;
z_rotation_matrix[14] = 0;
z_rotation_matrix[15] = 1;

GL20.glUniformMatrix4fv(
    GL20.glGetUniformLocation(programID, "x_rotation_matrix"), true, x_rotation_matrix);
GL20.glUniformMatrix4fv(
    GL20.glGetUniformLocation(programID, "y_rotation_matrix"), true, y_rotation_matrix);
GL20.glUniformMatrix4fv(
    GL20.glGetUniformLocation(programID, "z_rotation_matrix"), true, z_rotation_matrix);
```

Here is my transformation matrix:

```
trans_matrix[0] = 1;
trans_matrix[5] = 1;
trans_matrix[10] = 1;
trans_matrix[12] = x;
trans_matrix[13] = y;
trans_matrix[14] = z;
trans_matrix[15] = 1;
```

---

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're off by 1 in your matrix initialization. 
The matrix rows are 4 entries wide (4x4 matrix) but you're initializing them like they're 3 entries wide.

```
z_rotation_matrix[0] = (float) cos(-pitch * (PI / 180));// * (PI / 180));
z_rotation_matrix[1] = (float) -sin(-pitch * (PI / 180));// * (PI / 180));
z_rotation_matrix[2] = 0;
z_rotation_matrix[3] = (float) sin(-pitch * (PI / 180));// * (PI / 180));
z_rotation_matrix[4] = (float) cos(-pitch * (PI / 180));// * (PI / 180));
z_rotation_matrix[5] = 1;
z_rotation_matrix[6] = 0;
```

Should be

```
z_rotation_matrix[0] = (float) cos(-pitch * (PI / 180));// * (PI / 180));
z_rotation_matrix[1] = (float) -sin(-pitch * (PI / 180));// * (PI / 180));
z_rotation_matrix[2] = 0;
z_rotation_matrix[3] = 0;
z_rotation_matrix[4] = (float) sin(-pitch * (PI / 180));// * (PI / 180));
z_rotation_matrix[5] = (float) cos(-pitch * (PI / 180));// * (PI / 180));
z_rotation_matrix[6] = 0;
```

And so on.

```
x_rotation_matrix[4] = (float) cos(-yaw * (PI / 180));//);// * (PI / 180)
x_rotation_matrix[5] = (float) -sin(-yaw * (PI / 180));// * (PI / 180));
x_rotation_matrix[6] = 0;
x_rotation_matrix[7] = (float) sin(-yaw * (PI / 180));// * (PI / 180));
x_rotation_matrix[8] = (float) cos(-yaw * (PI / 180));// * (PI / 180));
x_rotation_matrix[9] = 0;
x_rotation_matrix[10] = 1;
```

Should be

```
x_rotation_matrix[4] = 0;
x_rotation_matrix[5] = (float) cos(-yaw * (PI / 180));//);// * (PI / 180)
x_rotation_matrix[6] = (float) -sin(-yaw * (PI / 180));// * (PI / 180));
x_rotation_matrix[7] = 0;
x_rotation_matrix[8] = 0;
x_rotation_matrix[9] = (float) sin(-yaw * (PI / 180));// * (PI / 180));
x_rotation_matrix[10] = (float) cos(-yaw * (PI / 180));// * (PI / 180));
x_rotation_matrix[11] = 0;
x_rotation_matrix[12] = 0;
```

Same issue with `y_rotation_matrix`.

Comment: Is this what you mean? [link] (http://pastebin.com/VXKYA6tG)

Comment: Y rotation is still off. change [6] to [8] and [8] to [10]. But X and Z seem fine now.